# Shorthand self reference in Numpy indexing expressions

Tags: python, numpy, dry, self, shorthand

Is there a more efficient way to reference the outer array in a NumPy array indexing expression? I often find that with verbosely named NumPy arrays, the indexing expressions get ugly real fast. For example:

```py
other_precice_array = precicely_named_array[(precicely_named_array > num) | (precicely_named_array.isodd())]
```

To me, using three references to "precicely_named_array" seems a bit unweildy. I would really prefer to be able to refer to the array in shorthand while indexing like so:

```py
other_precice_array = precicely_named_array[(self > num) | (self.isodd())]
```

or

```py
other_precice_array = precicely_named_array[(np.me > num) | (np.me.isodd())]
```

This syntax would also have the added benefit of making it more obvious when the array being sliced was dependent on a different array. See:

```py
other_precice_array = precicely_named_array[(different_array > num) | (self.isodd())]
```

Is there any way to do that? Or a reason that I'm missing as to why I don't *really* want this?

I thought that the functions like np.where and np.choose might offer a solution, but they still require multiple references to the sliced array.

P.S. I realize that there are other ways to make the expression cleaner like separating the slicing expression into it's own variable, or just using shorter names, but for the purpose of this question I'm not interested in those answers.

Comment: I don't think so. You could just use a shorter variable name so it's not so verbose. You can do `this = precisely_named_array` and then use `this` inside the index.

Comment: keep in mind that it's python that's running this.  `x[z]` is a numpy indexing call, but `z` is evaluated in full first. And if `z` is `(a | b)`, then each of those terms is evaluated first.  `numpy` doesn't change python syntax or evaluation order.

Comment: Just use another variable with a shorter name, there is no "outer" array, indeed, Python has no idea that any arrays are involved at the level of syntax

Comment: Numpy is just a library. It can't change the language (python). And what you are asking for is a language alteration. That would be a generic python thing that allows right hand of a assignment to refer with a simple symbol to the array of a "setindex" operation.

Comment: If you really need to, you can do `other_precice_array = (lambda s: s[(s > num) | (s.isodd())])(precicely_named_array)` but that's probably harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python 3.8+, use a temporary variable name with the walrus operator `:=`.

```
other_precice_array = (_ := precicely_named_array)[(_ > num) | _.isodd()]
```

Comment: Or `_=precisely_named_array ; other_precise_array=_[(_>num) | _.isodd()]`

Comment: It other words just use a simpler variable name (at least as an alias, while keeping the old big name) if you find the big one too complicated.

Comment: Or `other_precice_array = (_ := precicely_named_array)[(_ > num) | (_.isodd())]` keeping with the spirit of the original answer

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't automatically keep named references to values in expressions - and it would be hard to do something like that in a sensible way.

You could put the calculation in function using a terse name

```
def large_and_odd(arr, n):
    return arr[(arr > n) | (arr.isodd())])
    
other_precice_array = large_and_odd(precicely_defined_array, num)
```

This could be done in an existing function or at module level. And using functions for clarity is fair game. You could also do with with a lambda, but it would be puzzling to future readers how it works and why you did it. But, ...

```
other_precice_array = (lambda arr, n: arr[(arr > n) | (arr.isodd())])\
    (precicely_defined_array, num)
```

Comment: I think this is probably the right solution in some cases, but at least in my experience, indexing expressions tend to be one-offs (only useful in their specific context), and where that's true I think making a function is a bit less readable than using the walrus operator inline... Still, this is a good answer.